# hAxis viewWindow and ticks returns a bad graph, but vAxis works well

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I am doing a graph of a Tesla charge curve and use Google Charts

```
[function drawChart() {
      var data =  google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(\[
      \['SoC',  'Power'\],
      <?php echo $entry; ?>

      \]);

      var options = {
      title: 'Charge curve',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' },
      vAxis: { title: 'Power', viewWindow: { min: 0, max: 150 }, ticks: \[0, 37.5, 75, 112.5, 150\] },
      hAxis: { title: 'SoC', viewWindow: { min: 0, max: 100 }, ticks: \[0, 25, 50, 75, 100\] }
       };


      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));


      chart.draw(data, options);
      }][1]
```

The hAxis viewWindow and ticks dont work. I want the x-axis to always go from 0 to 100, with lines every 25 since it is percentage.

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data?

Comment: string(610) "['13',14],['13',67],['13',73],['14',93],['14',131],['15',137],['16',137],['17',137],['18',137],['18',137],['19',137],['22',135],['23',135],['26',135],['27',135],['28',135],['28',135],['29',135],['30',135],['31',135],['31',135],['32',135],['33',134],['34',135],['35',135],['36',135],['36',135],['37',135],['38',135],['39',135],['40',133],['40',117],['41',107],['42',102],['42',98],['43',97],['45',95],['46',95],['68',68],['68',68],['69',67],['69',66],['69',65],['70',64],['71',60],['72',60],['72',59],['72',58],['73',57],['73',56],['75',50],['76',50],['77',46],['77',46],['77',45],"

Comment: MySQL: soc TINYINT NOT NULL,    power SMALLINT NOT NULL

Comment: I see now that there is a String, which doesnt auto-cast to int. I will dig into it. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed, thanks a ton!